# I'm new to python and i don't know what's wrong with the code

Tags: python, function

I just created a simple function and when i called the function it stops working in the middle when i say yes

```
def game():
    K = input("are you ready?")
    if K == "no":
                 return None
    if K == "yes":  
                I = input("what is 881 divisible by")
    if I == ( 1 , 881):
            print("you won")
    else:
            print("better luck next time")
```

I tried it and i was expecting it to work when it stopped working after the if K == yes

i don't know what went wrong

Comment: I think you meant to indent the `if I ==...` part

Comment: Also `I == (1, 881)` will never be true, you're comparing a string to a tuple.

Comment: what do you mena by "stopped working" ?

Comment: In Python 2, `input` would evaluate an input of `(1, 881)` to a tuple, compared to Python 3 which will return the string `'(1, 881)'`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole structure of the code is messy (there is no proper indentation, which is causing the confusion)
You might want to clean it up like so:-

```py
def game():
        K = input("are you ready?")
        if K == "no":
                return None
        elif K == "yes":  
                I = input("what is 881 divisible by")
                if I == ( 1 , 881):
                        print("you won")
                else:
                        print("better luck next time")
```

Also, for the case of `no`, it should be included in the else part since it is really doing nothing, so you can remove that part and make it just `if K =="yes":`

```
def game():
        K = input("are you ready?")
        if K == "yes":  
                I = input("what is 881 divisible by")
                if I == ( 1 , 881):
                        print("you won")
                else:
                        print("better luck next time")
```

Assuming that `( 1 , 881)` are the correct answers, you don't need to make them numbers and instead make them strings, and either make them contained in a list like `["1", "881"]` and then check whether the value of `I` is in the list, or you can use `or` keyword

Using `["1", "881"]` :

```
...
I = input("what is 881 divisible by")
if I in ["1", "881"]:
        print("you won")
else:
        print("better luck next time")
```

Using `or` keyword :

```
...
I = input("what is 881 divisible by")
if I == "1" or I == "881":
        print("you won")
else:
        print("better luck next time")
```

Comment: also is there anything wrong with using variables for input because i do have some problems with them

Comment: @AnudeepRathod variables are used with inputs to collect and store the value of the input which the user enters. I suggest you look up some tutorials on basics of Python.

Comment: Well i am in the middle of a tutorial